# Vue Node.js extract cf-ipcountry cloudflare from request headers

Tags: node.js, vue.js, cloudflare

I'm currently using vue js nuxt for my projects. I'm having trouble parsing request headers to retrieve
cf-ipcountry provided by cloudflare. use case for this is to display different content for different country

My code look something like this under my vue file

```
   async asyncData(context) {  
    try{
     const countryCF = context.req.headers['cf-ipcountry'] 
    }
   }
```

when i try to console.log(countryCF) it won't return it, but if i try to console.log(context.req.headers['cf-ipcountry']) it works fine, it did print out the whole headers, but i just need the cf-ipcountry, did i miss anything? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized the reason is due to Nuxt SSR initial load is from server side but subsequent request will be client side thats why its returning error

```
  if (process.server) {
      context.app.$cookiz.set('user-country', context.req.headers['cf-ipcountry']) 
  }
```

Solve by if process.server and i'm storing it in cookie with this package
https://www.npmjs.com/package/cookie-universal-nuxt

Answer (score 0):

I used the following:

```
const country_code = req.headers['cf-ipcountry'] ?? 'unknown';
```

It worked well for me and did not print the whole headers, just the 2-letter country code.